# Hide table if certain selections within a parameter are selected

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

I have an SSRS report that has two tables inside the report.  I can normally hide or display them utilizing something like the below in the report properties visibility-hidden section.

=iif(Parameters!AutoDrillDown.Value = 2, true, false)

How would I do this if not looking at the actual parameter but the values in the parameter?  For instance, if the end-user selects Option A,and B in the parameter it will display the first table.  If C and D, the second table.  If A,B,C, and D...both tables?  Can this be done in that section?  I am really not that good with SQL so any advice would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Just expand the IIF statement to include all variations of the parameter on each table visibility.

Comment: how do I do that?  Is there an example of what it would look like?  I am not very good at this.

Comment: Basing my answer below on what you stated above.

Answer (score 0):

If I undestand your question correctly your parameter is set to allow multiple values.

Try this for table 1:

```
=IIF(
Array.IndexOf(Parameters!AutoDrillDown.Value,"OptionA")>-1 AND
Array.IndexOf(Parameters!AutoDrillDown.Value,"OptionB")>-1,false,true
)
```

And this for table 2:

```
=IIF(
Array.IndexOf(Parameters!AutoDrillDown.Value,"OptionC")>-1 AND
Array.IndexOf(Parameters!AutoDrillDown.Value,"OptionD")>-1,false,true
)
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I will try this right now.  Yes.  There are multiple values embedded in the parameter when I run the SSRS report.